# How to change TabControl selected tab

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I have a `TabControl` on a window which has three tabs in total. I would like to select the first tab programmatically. I've tried `TabControlMain.SelectedItem = 0`, but this doesn't work. How can I do this?

```xml
<TabControl x:Name="TabControlMain">
    <TabItem x:Name="TabItemA" Header="A">
        ...
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem x:Name="TabItemB" Header="B">
        ...
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem x:Name="TabItemC" Header="C">
        ...
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `TabControl.SelectedIndex = 0` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex))

Or set `YourDesiredTabItem.IsSelected = true` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tabitem.isselected))

`TabControl.SelectedItem` can only be a `TabItem` object or `null` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem)).